How to save a storage (IStorage) object to a file (С++)?
I have got a storage, created from MS Outlook letter dragged to my window.
How can I save it's (storage) contents as a file in a single file ?
I have read MSDN about manipulations with storages - StgCreateDocfile creates (if I am right) a new storage, but I need to save an existing one.


StgCreateDocfile(..., &new_storage); creates an empty or opens an existing file storage.
existing_storage->CopyTo(0, nullptr, nullptr, new_storage) copies
an existing storage to a file storage.


3CxEZiVlQ, Thank you very much! It's more theoretical question - it seems to me it may be too expensive to make a copy of a storage just to save it. Why a "direct save" (without making a copy) is not implemented ?

You can use the stream interface, but it will require much more to code.

3CxEZiVlQ, could you at least a little bit tell me about main action to program it. Can I somehow "convert" the storage to a stream (how) ?

Сould anybody advise me a way, how can I "convert" the storage (I have got an IStorage object) to a IStream ?

Please post a new question. Comments are not for new questions.
